# Finding pid of background process from c prog

Tags: c, unix

I am writing a program for creating a shell which handles basic functionalities such as executing basic commands,piping,redirection,executing background process.However i am not being able to kill a background process, i need to know the pid() of the background process so that i can send a kill call along with the pid.Any idea how to get the pid() of a background process from a c pogram?
For running the commands I am taking input from commandline into an array,parsing it and putting the command in arr[0] and the subsequent arguments in the subsequent indexes,i am taking the PATH of the system into another array and storing them as strings by using strtok and delim option as :,after this i am concatenating the path with the command,and then doing an execv().

I am stuck with this part where i have to kill a background process.Any suggestion would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but `execv()` does not create a new process, but replaces the current program with a new one, wiouth changing the PID! You have to call `fork()` to create a new process. And `fork()` return the PID of the new process...

Comment: i am calling fork and then doing an execv in child process,..but how do i get the pid of a background process??

Comment: Did you ever bother to read the documentation for fork(2)? Stackoverflow is not a replacement for your man pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0) {
        execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", (char *) 0);
    } else {
        waitpid(pID, NULL, 0); // wait for child process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fork` returns the PID of the child in the parent process, store it someplace and then use it to kill?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [getpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) (in the childprosses), or the pid of the child is returned to the parent when calling [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)